How to detect the procedure name?
I run the VS project with Code Analysis, and I get this message:

SR0014 : Microsoft.Rules.Data : Data loss might occur when casting
from NVarChar(200) to NVarChar(10).

How can I find where this has been detected, in what stored procedure?
I have > 200 stored procedures ....

The Error List (at the bottom of the linked image) displays the file name.

Visual Studio should already be giving you sufficient context to identify the SP, but if it isn't, try running the following code:
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS ProcedureName, definition
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE definition LIKE '%NVarChar(200)%'
   OR definition LIKE '%CAST(%NVarChar(10)%'


ok but I receive 350 results. It is not a way

SELECT DISTINCT?
